# How to create an image of mean values from multiple NDVI images?

Tags: qgis, ndvi, terrset

I have downloaded MODIS NDVI images of 12 months. I would like to create just 1 image with the mean values. I tried using IDRISI's 'NDVI compositing utility', but I get an error. Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Have you looked into using the Raster Calculator? http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a visual for using "Raster Calculator" in qgis.  This tool is located in the "Raster" tab in the QGIS.

[image: RATER CALC]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the GRASS [r.series](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.series.html) command in QGIS to accomplish this.  Make sure to select the "average" statistic.

> r.series - Makes each output cell value a function of the values
>   assigned to the corresponding cells in the input raster map layers.